# Auto migrations with sequelize and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, migration, sequelize.js, nestjs

I'm researching the ability to generate migration files for existing models. For example if I use "force: true" mode, tables in database are creating automatically so I can't believe that creating migrations files automatically is impossible. So could you help me with advice?

Comment: Do you want model files to be generated from existing database?

Comment: Prabhjot, no, I just wont to generate migration files from existing models with typescript

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by creating migrations using sequelize-cli in JS file and importing it in my TypeScript file.

This way only the migrations are in JS while the other parts are in TS